# Push $scope with ng-click AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want the user to press the $scope.getJobList button to get the value of the $scope.getIdJobs variable. I am trying to solve this with the push functionality but it is not working.
Am I doing something wrong?

[jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11883/)

Example

```
$scope.getIdJobs = function(getIdJobs) {   

    $scope.getIdJobs = $filter('filter')( $scope.products, {id:getIdJobs})[0];

         $scope.getJobList = function(currObj){
                $scope.workflows[0].Steps.push($scope.getIdJobs); // It will add a new step ($scope.newStep) in first workflow's Steps
                console.log($scope.workflows);
            //$scope.workflows.push($scope.getIdJobs); // line that changed
            $scope.workflows = job_detail.addJob(currObj)
            console.log($scope.workflows);
        };

    //console.log("Estou dentro do getidJobs " + getIdJobs);
}
```

html

```
       <article dir-paginate="product in filteredJobs | filter:searchTerm | orderBy: sorting.order:sorting.direction | itemsPerPage:5" id="{{product.id}}" class="productlist product col-sm-12"> 
            <div class="inner-content">
                <div class="clearfix">                       
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                        <h4 class="productname" name="{{product.Categoria}}"><a data-ng-href="#/job/{{product.id}}" ng-click="getIdJobs(product.id)">{{product.Title}}</a></h4>
                        <!--<h4 class="productname" name="{{product.Categoria}}"><a data-ng-href="#/job/{{filteredJobs.indexOf(product)}}">{{product.Title}}</a></h4>-->
                        <h4 style="color: gray;"><a data-ng-href="#/empresa">{{product.Empresa}}</a></h4>

                    </div>                        

                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
```

Comment: can you add working code snippet please?

Comment: see if the jsfiddle is good

Comment: what's in the `$scope.products` ?

Comment: nothing is displayed.... You need to add some static json data to it according to your json structure, then only can debug your issue

Comment: Your JSFiddle is not working: no controller defitnition, no ngApp directive...

Comment: you didn't inject `$filter`

Comment: i update the jsfiddle again but i need change one thing because he dont get the json

Comment: Where is your `ng-app` attribute?

Comment: I just need to get the $ scope.getIdJobs in function $ scope.getJobList that's why I did not put the whole code

Comment: If you do not put the correct code, your code do not work. You need ngApp directive.

Comment: idk what i miss i put all the code but don't show the product.title but what i need is the  $ scope.getIdJobs in function $ scope.getJobList that's why I did not put the whole code. I update the jsfiddle 5 times

Comment: This part is wierd `$scope.getIdJobs = function(getIdJobs) {   

    $scope.getIdJobs = $filter('filter')( $scope.products, {id:getIdJobs})[0];` This shouldn't be something like  `$scope.filteredJob = $filter('filter')( $scope.products, {id:getIdJobs})[0];`

Comment: Your JSFiddle has errors! Do not you understand what is a functional testing code!?